# Nikon D3100 unusable after update

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100

I have a problem with my Nikon D3100 after an update. Updating went apparently fine but now it won't restart. Nothing happens when I press the "on" button.

What can I do?

<sub>[Original question was in French.  It is viewable in the edit history if you'd like to see it. ~ @Cullub]</sub>

Comment: Ecrives en Anglaise, S'il vous plait?  Toute le StackExchange-monde ne peut parler en Francaise.  <--  and that sure includes me!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, Olivier added a translation 17 hours before you made that comment.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft my camera not working Because this update not complet please help me

Comment: @PeterTaylor   geez, do I need to use the <humor>  tag on **every** comment?

Comment: Did you do the obvious things like checking the battery?   And if it's OK,  there's a trick that works with some electronic gadgets:  remove the battery, wait a few minutes for things to completely shut down, then put the battery back in and see if the camera recovers.

Answer (score 1):

Pull the battery. Put the battery in a charger to make sure it's fully charged. With the battery out of the camera, press and hold the 'on' button for 20 or 30 seconds. Make sure there is a working memory card installed. Put the fully charged battery into the camera.  Press the 'On' button. Magic may occur.